# PHP/MySQL Friend Request System

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use the php code found here: http://www.thetechideas.com/how-to-make-friendship-request-system-in-php/

And I am encountering a WHOLE lot of errors, I'm not sure why. I think it might have something to do with their question marks and apostrophes but I'm not sure.

I've made quite a few errors go away by messing with the quotation makes and apostrophes, but I am still getting errors? Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post the errors you are getting and the corresponding code?

Comment: @max_ Okay, well with the code in Pé de Leão's answer I am getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /friendship.php on line 17

Comment: That's because the echo isn't escaped. Use this: `echo(“<form method=\”POST\”>
<input type=\”text\” name=\”username\” value=\”Type username here\”>
<input type=\”submit\” name=\”submit\”>`
</form>”);

Comment: Thats still giving me the same error?

Comment: That's an awful piece of code. Don't use it.

Comment: Yeah, im not using that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That code is not a good example, it uses the contents of $_GET directly in SQL statements, and puts these values into the session.  These are not good practices.  They are terribly insecure.

All values read from the Internet should be validated and the SQL should be built using prepared statements.  Doing these will make your code far more secure and will reduce the number of quotes needed to build the SQL.  You should use mysqli or better yes PDO to allow prepared statements.

Comment: How would you suggest making the user friend request system? Besides the get?

Comment: I mean is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Take the code and work on understanding what it does. Then rewrite it to use best practices, read the $_GET daw, validate it and then use the validated value.  Use parameterized SQL statements (prepared statements) to get better security and far fewer quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be hard to figure out exactly why this is breaking for you, but at first glance I see there are a lot of quotes, single and double, and question-marks, and I wouldn't be surprised if since you're having to dork around with those at all the encoding just isn't going to work? You may also have made mistakes editing it, too. What editor are you copying this into? If you paste it into something like eclipse instead do you you still get errors?

Comment: I am using text wrangler, its the Notepad++ equivalent for Mac, what difference/effect do the different text editors have?

Comment: I was just thinking it might have detected some of these problems and made the fixes for you. If text wrangler is like npp, I don't think it would. At any rate, you might want to edit your question to provide the specific errors you're encountering.